# Hibernate: map field from another table

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have three tables:
Table A with fields

```
id
```

Table B with fields

```
id
```

Table C with fields

```
id_a
id_b
```

being `id_a` and `id_b` references to the `id` of Table A and the `id` of Table B respectively. The postgres definition of Table C looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE C (
    id_a BIGINT          NOT NULL REFERENCES a(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    id_b BIGINT          NOT NULL REFERENCES b(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT c_pkey
        PRIMARY KEY (a, b)
);
```

However in my code I don't need an entity for table C. So I want to be able to map in a @ManyToOne relationship entities A and B:

```
@Entity
public class A {
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "C",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_a", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_b", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private B b;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class B {
    private Long id;
}
```

I have a test that looks like this:

```
    @Test
    void shouldFindBForA() {
        //given
        var a = new A();
        var b = new B();

        aRepository.saveAndFlush(a);
        bRepository.saveAndFlush(b);
        //when
        A foundA = aRepository.findAll().get(0);
        //then
        assertThat(foundA.getB()).isNotNull();
    }
```

which fails in the `isNotNull` assertion.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

both @JoinColumn pointing to the same id "id_a"

Comment: That was a typo. I edited the question